# Using an Android phone with a Mac's messaging App

Tags: mac, android

Several of my friends have their iPhones hooked up to the iMessage app on Mac. 
If you're not familiar, it lets you check your phones messages as well as send messages on your Mac via your phone.

I was hoping there was a Android - Mac equivalent of this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Macbook but also love my Nexus 6P. I was looking for the same thing and I found [iMessage for Android](https://android-imessages.fortifiedlabs.com) which does exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. iMessage was designed by Apple exclusively for Mac O/S and IOS. you want iMessage you'll have to get an iPhone or Mac.